# how to add newline when printing to console in luacode function?

Tags: formatting, luatex, lua

I'd like to print to the console (not back to latex) from inside luacode function.

But I am not able to figure how to do it. When I add `\n` it does not like it. I am using `print` from inside lua to print out to the console as the file is compiled using `lualatex`.

It works ok without `\n` but wanted to add newline between parts of the string to make it easier to see on scree. This is just for debugging. Not related to lua sending anything back to latex.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function foo(s) 
    print("the input is \n"..s.."\nwhich was send by Latex")
 end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

\directlua{ foo(\luastring{some stuff})}

test

\end{document}
```

Compiling using `lualatex foo3.tex` gives

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> function foo(s)
print("the input is \n
                                       "..s.."\nwhich  was send by Latex")
end
l.8 \end{luacode}
```

There must be another way to do this, other than using "\n" but have not been able to find it. Without "\n" it works OK. so this works

```
   print("the input is "..s.."which was send by Latex")
```

And now when compiled, I see on the screen this:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./foo3.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)the input is some stuffwhich was send by Latex

(./foo3.aux))
 413 words of node memory still in use:
```

No errors.

Using TL 2020.

```
lualatex --version
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the luacode* environment:

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function foo(s)
    print("the input is \n"..s.."\nwhich was send by Latex")
 end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

\directlua{ foo(\luastring{some stuff})}

test

\end{document}
```

or use \string

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function foo(s)
    print("the input is \string\n"..s.."\string\nwhich was send by Latex")
 end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

\directlua{ foo(\luastring{some stuff})}

test

\end{document}
```

Or move your code in some external lua file and load it with require.